# Refresh fast on commit with groupby and where clause

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, materialized-views

I am able to successfully create a materialized view such as below however when I look at MV_CAPABILITIES_TABLE, it is telling me that REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML and REFRESH_FAST_ANY_DML is not possible.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_contacts_table
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT AS
SELECT t.ID AS ID,
MAX(DECODE(t.FieldName, 'FirstName', t.FieldValue)) FirstName, 
MAX(DECODE(t.FieldName, 'LastName', t.FieldValue)) LastName,
COUNT(*) AS NUM_FIELDS FROM Contacts_Table t
WHERE t.FieldName = 'FirstName' OR t.FieldName = 'LastName'
GROUP BY t.ID
```

Here the MV_CAPABILITIES_TABLE

```
PCT                             N               
REFRESH_COMPLETE                Y               
REFRESH_FAST                    Y               
REWRITE                         N               
PCT_TABLE                       N   CONTACTS_TABLE  675 2068    relation is not a partitioned table
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT       Y               
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML   N                       2086    mv uses the MIN or MAX aggregate functions
REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ANY_DML      N                       2161    see the reason why REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML is disabled
REFRESH_FAST_PCT                N                       2157    PCT is not possible on any of the detail tables in the materialized view
REWRITE_FULL_TEXT_MATCH         N                       2159    query rewrite is disabled on the materialized view
REWRITE_PARTIAL_TEXT_MATCH      N                       2159    query rewrite is disabled on the materialized view
REWRITE_GENERAL                 N                       2159    query rewrite is disabled on the materialized view
REWRITE_PCT                     N                       2158    general rewrite is not possible or PCT is not possible on any of the detail tables
PCT_TABLE_REWRITE               N   CONTACTS_TABLE  675 2068    relation is not a partitioned table
```

If I remove the where clause the REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ANY_DML is possible. Is there any possibility that this SQL query can be tweaked so that my materialized view set to REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ANY_DML with including Where clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [restriction of materialized views](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/basicmv.htm#GUID-932B8CD4-BF60-419A-9202-8A9FD5D24024):

> A materialized view with MAX or MIN is fast refreshable after delete
>   or mixed DML statements **if it does not have a WHERE clause**.
>
> The max/min fast refresh after delete or mixed DML does not have the
>   same behavior as the insert-only case. It deletes and recomputes the
>   max/min values for the affected groups. You need to be aware of its
>   performance impact.

(emphasis mine).

So you need to find some other way to achieve your goal.

Comment: @chrisrsaxon Since I have the requirement to store custom key value pairs, I came up with above table structure. And the reason why I want to create materialized views is because the performance of transpose is very poor. Would JSON column be the right choice to store such things? Will I will able to create materialized views on JSON column?